# How can i execute a link in a php page

Tags: php

I have a test.php page

in this page , there is a url . i need to execute that url (here database updation is doing).This is my code

```
<?php
$username ='testUsername';
if($_GET['age']!=''){
header('location:www.test.com/update.php?age='.$_GET['age'].'&username='.$username); //need to updatethe age of this username
 $show ='hello';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $show ?>
</body>
</html>
```

i know this code is not going to work properly.How can i write in a good way.I donot want  to redirect the page.I just need to execute that link

Comment: Is your website on www.test.com or is that some external website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `file_get_contents` on the url in question instead of setting the location header to that value.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `update.php` file is hosted on an external website, the only thing you can do is get the contents of the *output* of the file. (Use `file_get_contents` to get that output.) That is, it will call the file (with your parameters) and you can fetch the HTML result of it—nothing more. It would be a major security problem if server files could be executed on external websites.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include the code in update.php without redirecting, you can do so with the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) functions.

> require() is identical to include()
>   except upon failure it will ... halt
>   the script whereas include() only
>   emits a warning (E_WARNING) which
>   allows the script to continue.

Comment: But this test.php file is not in www.test.com

Comment: While including works (you can just call include on a full URL), it also has the nasty side effects that if the file in question had any output, it will be included in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IMG tag. `<img widht=0 height=0 src="<?='location:www.test.com/update.php?age='.$_GET['age'].'&username='.$username ?>" />`

Comment: That makes little sense - it's completely unreliable and unnecessary. What if the user uses lynx?